# ALTER DATABASE... SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL -- will this impact log shipping? Can it be done live?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2017 Standard Ed

I have a database that is at level 2008.

I want to bring it up to current.

This database log ships.

Is it safe to run:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name   
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = <whatever>
```

1- Live , when the app is running (I know the app is compatible with the new level)

2- Will this break or mess with log shipping?

Comment: I don't think it will but I cannot find conclusive 100% for sure source anywhere but this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/029d892d-9dd6-4d3b-bbb9-5e3eca8b8936/modifying-compatibility-mode-and-effect-on-logshipping-replication-clustering-and-cdc?forum=sqldatabaseengine may clarify some perhaps (again I cannot confirm personally though)... Also search https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017 for "*replication*" and read over its **note** section.

Comment: More than anything else will this break compatibility Of queries or objects, you should ask. Use the Microsoft [Migration assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/sql-server-migration-assistant), which is fully supported by Microsoft and even does some cool stuff now depending on the version. 

Comment: @clifton_h I have already established that my queries and objects are fully compatible with the new compatibility_level.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in off hours or when you have less activity on the server. Doing when the server is busy, will incur blocking.

Changing compatibility level does not impact logshipping, Mirroring or AlwaysON along with replication.  I have done it safely during less activity time.

Comment: This is correct. When you change the DBCompat level of a database on a busy server you may experience blocking. There is no issue with DBCompat and any HA/DR feature of SQL Server.